# getting content from CSS3 pseudo element using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently learning web scraping using Python and Beautiful Soup. I am given a task in which the web page is having star rating inside css pseudo element

```
<span class="bb_rating bble_50">
  ::before
  ::after 
</span>

bble_50::after {
  content: "\e00b\e00b\e00b\e00b\e00b";
}
```

[image]

I want to know how can I get the content from css psuedo element?
Need help. Thanks

Comment: Looks like a trip advisor. Is not it? Could you show how do you get the page source in the first place? Thanks.

Comment: yes, it is from trip advisor, but my mentor just changed some css, so that I cant copy paste from anywhere. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you should actually go to parsing CSS here. Just *map out the class names to ratings*:

```
class_to_rating = {
    "bble_45": 4.5,
    "bble_50": 5
}
elm = soup.select_one(".bb_rating")
rating_class = next(value for value in elm["class"] if value.startswith("bble_"))

print(class_to_rating.get(rating_class, "Unknown rating"))
```

Comment: It sounds good. Thanks for this. But is there any way I can actually get pseudo selector. I can get it using javascript, if I use Node.js

Comment: @raju well, there are CSS parsers like [`tinycss`](https://tinycss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). There is always regex. And, if `selenium` is a choice, it might help to get to the `content` css property via [`value_of_css_property`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.value_of_css_property)..

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps. Also can you please help in how can I get content after clicking 'More' inside 'partial_entry' class. Should I open another question for that.

Comment: @raju yes please, do create a new question. Thanks!

Comment: :: can you please explain how -- rating_class = next(value for value in elm["class"] if value.startswith("bble_")) -- works. I am new to python

Comment: @raju there is a built-in [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) in play here. It is a convenient way to filter a single item out from an iterator based on a condition.